# Is there a way to make a Denodo 8 VDP scheduler job WAIT() for a certain amount of time?

Tags: wait, scheduler, jobs, job-scheduling, denodo

I want to make a VDP scheduler job in Denodo 8 wait for a certain amount of time. The wait function in the job creation process is not working as expected so I figured I'd write it into the VQL. However when i try the suggested function from the documentation (https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/8.0/en/vdp/vql/stored_procedures/predefined_stored_procedures/wait) the Denodo 8 VQL shell doesn't recognize the function.

--Not working
SELECT WAIT('10000');

Returns the following error:
Function 'wait' with arity 1 not found

--Not working
WAIT('10000');

Returns the following error:
Error parsing command 'WAIT('10000')'

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/latest/en/vdp/vql/stored_procedures/predefined_stored_procedures/wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of invoking WAIT:

Option #1

```
-- Wait for one minute
CALL WAIT(60000);
```

Option #2:

```
-- Wait for ten seconds
SELECT timeinmillis 
FROM WAIT()
WHERE timeinmillis = 10000;
```